# Vue.js component is a fragment instance

Tags: browserify, vue.js

I've made my  like this:

```
  <main>
      <!-- router outlet -->
      <router-view
        class="view"
        keep-alive
        transition
        transition-mode="out-in">
      </router-view>
  </main>
```

In my console I receive the error:

```
main.js:5944 [Vue warn]: Attributes "class", "transition" are ignored on component <router-view> because the component is a fragment instance: http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instancewarn @ main.js:5944
main.js:5944 [Vue warn]: Transitions will not work on a fragment instance. Template: 
<banner :title="title"></banner>
<div class="login-view">
  <div class="Login-alert" v-show="authError" transition="fade">
    Foutieve combinatie email / wachtwoord
  </div>
  <form class="Login-form" @submit.prevent="login">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="Login-form__input" v-model="creds.email" placeholder="Email" required="">
    <input type="password" name="password" class="Login-form__input" v-model="creds.password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" required="">
    <button type="submit" class="Button Login-form__button">
      Login
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
warn @ main.js:5944
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That is a specific behavior documented here as #4: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance

Unsure of the exact reasoning behind it, but likely has to do with the fact the entire thing will be just swapped out in most cases (all cases in v2). Simple correction is to have an outer div that holds your router-view

**EDIT:**

Try this instead of your current version to ensure it even has anything to do with the code you've pasted or if it is the view being routed to...

```
<main>
    <div>Howdy</div>
</main>
```

If that works, and obviously it should, what is the body of your view that is loading?

**EDIT2:**

Oh, i think i see now from the console output bit, your view itself must have exactly one parent element. So really you need to do two things, the div wrapper before your router-view and a div wrapper of inside your actual view. Think of it this way, the stuff inside the template tag is essentially copy and pasted over top of (and completely removing) the router-view tags. When that happens there should only ever be ONE parent element in a component. The part that threw me long ago is that the template tag is NOT an element in that regard.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that. But already tried to put a div around it. That's not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try this to ensure it is even the area you think it is...hmm, a bit new to posting here, one sec...

Comment: I found out that when I remove the  ```<banner :title="title"></banner>``` from my component the error is gone. But that's not a solution.

Comment: Well, you have to wrap `<banner>` and rest of the template beneath it in another `<div>`

Comment: agreed with Linus Borg, jamie check the EDIT2 part of my response abvoe